# how to use ocr.recognize(URL []arg0, arg1, arg2, arg3); method

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, ocr

I am using ocr-java-api 15.0.1.

Language is java

**Scenario:** My application opens an pdf image in new tab.I get the url in a variable .( cannot download the PDF in local system due to PHI compliance)

**Target to Automate:** to use OCR on this url to read its contents and then search some text.

I am trying to use **ocr.recognize(URL []arg0, arg1, arg2, arg3)**; but do not understand  how to pass the url here

or is there any other way to achieve my target

Comment: What have you tried so far? What docs/tutos you are referring? What's the issue you are facing? Please put some code/error/exceptions/your_attempt/your_expectation/output_of_your_attempts etc.

Comment: I am refering to http://asprise.com/ocr/files/docs/javadoc/index.html?com/asprise/ocr/Ocr.html for section Recognise .
I am not getting any error but not able to understand how to use this

Comment: Based on your question.. How to pass URL...==>>  you should pass an array of URL objects. `new URL[] {new URL("http", "https:://url_string.com/path_any") }`. Correct me if I'm not getting you correctly.